# Mass changing Links in OneNote 2010

Tags: hyperlink, batch-rename, microsoft-onenote-2010

I am using OneNote extensively for my work.
For example one part of my work is reviewing incoming documents. I do an initial review and then get more specific reviews from members of my team. All this is organised in OneNote and I have therefore tons of links to the files of the specific documents.

Soon my file system will be changed though and therefore all the links will no longer be correct.
Is there a method of mass changing the links?
For example at the moment the structure is W:\folder_x\document_y
and in future it will be U:\folder_x\documtent_y

Answer (score 1):

I have now found a solution myself. There is an add on for OneNote macros which is called [Onetastic](http://omeratay.com/onetastic/?). On the website you can also download a selection of already programmed macros. One is "[Search and Replace in Hyperlinks](http://omeratay.com/onetastic/?r=macroland&id=8932C479DC874BA5ACA8172624095C11)". This macro will let you enter a phrase (or link-part) that you want to search for and then what you want to replace it with.

Caution is needed where one has uses spaces in links.